# Searching for facebook profiles in People Hub?

Tags: facebook, people-hub

How can I search for facebook profiles of people which I don't have as friends? When I press the search button I can only find people which I have in friends... My phone is with windows 7

Answer (score 5):

You can't, the people hub is by definition only people you know. If you want to search for profiles who you aren't friends with, you need to do it either the facebook app or the facebook site.

Comment: please consider marking as accepted :)